# PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Returning Strange Characters - Protected from Scraping?

Tags: php, parsing

I am using `file_get_html('URL')` of PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to get the source code of any website. However, I have problems getting the source of one specific website:

https://www.nkbm.si/tecajne-liste-menjalnica?currencyexchangetypeid=1

If I `echo $html` I receive some strange characters. Looks like website is protected from scrapping. Is this possible? Any way around?

Print screen of parsed html...

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: What strange characters are you talking about?

Comment: The server may return different content for different browsers and determine the browser by "User-agent" string. You can set HTTP headers for file_get_contents using "stream context" (check PHP documentation). Also check that your parser is configured to use the correct character set.

Comment: Inspect the response. It gives you [`Content-Encoding: gzip`](https://requestable.pieterhordijk.com/FZd7o). So either decode it or negotiate a different encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer. The source code was gziped. So I had to unzip it first.